# inconsistent jpos.xml loading

Tags: xml, applet, javapos

I have an applet that successfully load jpos.xml in both WinXP and W2003SRV, with both JRE 6.045 and 7.025(yes old and outdated both), but it works.  However the very same code fails to load jpos.xml in Win7Pro.  The loading is here.  javaPOS appears does not allow the explicit loading from a jar or war.  Can someone instruct to why the inconsistency and a solution?

```
 JposEntryRegistry registry = JposServiceLoader.getManager().
     getEntryRegistry();
registry.load();
```

UPDATE:
I tried to load the file directly with
       String location=this.getCodeBase.toString+"WEB-INF/classes/jpos.xml"
       registry.getRegPopulator.load(location);
with no results
If I try to open an InputStream through a URL, I get:
FileNotFound. 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/WEB-INF/classes/jpos.xml
How can I manually populate the Jpos registry if it fails with the standard approach(which violates "write once use everywhere" on Win7Pro.  Any insights anyone?

UPDATAE01
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997336/java-applet-cant-find-javapos-configuration-files), I put the parameters in the applet tag, still fails on Win7Pro, but perversely works on Win7Home(yes everything being equal).  Detecting registry.getSize()==0 I load the file, first time I see it cache and it does not populate the registry.  I have downloaded jpos113 and all the necessary jars.  I am loading it from root of the application context. Ideas for the inconsistent deployment?

Actually below is the uncached trace

network: Downloading resource: http://10.0.0.50:8083/10sdaanyd/jpos.xml
    Content-Length: 6,245
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://10.0.0.50:8083/10sdaanyd/jpos.xml to File C:\Users\ExecAssist00\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\58\60dbe6ba-72fcf580-temp
network: CleanupThread used 1 us

779  [thread applet-javapos.appletPOS_00-3] DEBUG javapos.appletPOS_00  - start:in registry==0:registry.getSize()=0
about to print classpath. urls.length= 1
/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre6/classes
codebase: http://10.0.0.50:8083/10sdaanyd/
jpos.JposException: Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry